# short names do not seem to work in tocloft package for added lists

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I added a new list (requirements) but the short names do not appear in the List of Requirements (LOR). Instead, all that appears in the LOR is the initial '['

The setup code is:

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}% to define requirements list for TOC,F,T
\newcommand{\listrequirementsname}{LIST OF REQUIREMENTS}
\newlistof[subsubsection]{requirement}{rqt}{\listrequirementsname}
\newcommand{\requirement}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{requirement}
\par\noindent\textbf{Rqt \therequirement. #1}
\addcontentsline{rqt}{requirement}{\protect\numberline{\therequirement}#1}\par}
```

The usage is:

```
\requirement[short name]{Interface 1 Connector hfjdkh jfdhf kjfd fjdjf jfd jfdj fjdfj fjda jfjdafih eiufhda fdaf fda oif}
```

The output in the LOR is:

> 3.2.1.1.1 [ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 8

And the output in the actual requirement is:

> Rqt 3.2.1.1.1. [
>   short name]Interface 1 Connector hfjdkh jfdhf kjfd fjdjf jfd jfdj fjdfj fjda   jfjdafih
>   eiufhda fdaf fda oif

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your current definition of `\requirement` is that it only takes one mandatory argument, that is used for both the document and for the entry in the new list.

You need to define `\requirement` with one optional argument (that, if present, will be used for the list) and a mandatory one; something along these lines (I also increased the space reserved for the numbers in the new list):

```
\documentclass[titles,subfigure]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\listrequirementsname}{LIST OF REQUIREMENTS}
\newlistof[subsubsection]{requirement}{rqt}{\listrequirementsname}

\newcommand{\requirement}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{requirement}
\par\noindent\textbf{Rqt \therequirement. #2}
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}{}}
  {\addcontentsline{rqt}{requirement}{\protect\numberline{\therequirement}#2}\par}
  {\addcontentsline{rqt}{requirement}{\protect\numberline{\therequirement}#1}\par}
}

\setlength\cftrequirementnumwidth{4em}

\begin{document}
\listofrequirement
\requirement[short name]{Interface 1 Connector}
\requirement{Interface 2 Connector}

\end{document}
```

[image]